# How to avoid downtime when using docker rollout with Traefik?

Tags: docker, traefik, high-availability

I want to make sure that there is zero downtime when I deploy a new version of a Docker container.

For this I've started using Traefik and [`docker rollout`](https://github.com/Wowu/docker-rollout). The idea that I had was that docker rollout would start a new instance of my app, run it in parallel with the old version, then stop the old version, and Traefik would know to balance requests between the old and the new one.

However I'm trying to verify that it works with `ab -n 1000 -c 3` and I still get failed requests. I would imagine that's because rollout doesn't notify Traefik that it's about to kill the old container and the requests that are currently in progress get dropped?

How can this be avoided? Is there a way to make rollout tell Traefik that the old instance is about to get stopped, so stop sending any more requests there?

Comment: Are you aware of traefik.docker.lbswarm (https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/docker/) that might make a difference

Comment: Maintainer here. I created [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Wowu/docker-rollout/issues/21) to discuss what is the best way to implement this.